# Installing numpy for python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to draw a graph using Python and from my research the easiest way seems to be by installing numpy and matplotlib. However, I'm having problems trying to install both.

So far I've tried using pip in the command line, as well as downloading the zip file from pypi.

I'm using Python 3.6 if that helps!

Comment: Use one of the [scientific distributions](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#third-party-distributions-of-matplotlib). I recommend anaconda.

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: What is your error? You need to be more specific if you want us to help

Answer (score 3):

If using Windows, open cmd and type:
`python -m pip install numpy`

But I recommend you just install the Anaconda distribution of Python which comes with everything you need now and things you will need in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've installed Anaconda and it's working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the wheels for numpy and matplotlib.

Or install anaconda and it will come with numpy and matplotlib.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib

Comment: Thank you so much! I've installed Anaconda and it's working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

use anaconda IDE after installing anaconda you don't need to install pip ,numpy because it's automatically install anaconda numpy matplotlib

Comment: Thank you so much! I've installed Anaconda and it's working fine now :)